# Bash: Scriptception, create scripts inside a script

Tags: bash

How would i create a script that creates two separate scripts with something inside them?

i tried this but failed

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > scriptMaster.sh << EOF

   cat > script1.sh << EOF
   #code
   EOF

   cat > script2.sh << EOF
   #code
   EOF

EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must put the `EOF` marker at the left margin, unless you prefix it with `-`, which allows it to be indented with <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters, but *not* spaces. You'll need to use different EOF markers for the outer and inner here-docs; otherwise, the marker will terminate the outer one as soon as it's seen (since the inner here-docs aren't actually executed until you run the `scriptMaster.sh` script).

```
#!/bin/bash
cat >scriptMaster.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
cat > script1.sh <<EOF1
#!/bin/bash
#code
EOF1
chmod +x script1.sh # Make the script executable

cat >script2.sh <<EOF2
#!/bin/bash
#code
EOF2
chmod +x script2.sh

EOF
chmod +x scriptMaster.sh

#Now run the scripts:
./scriptMaster.sh
./script1.sh
./script2.sh
```

Comment: are the two EOF2 mistake?

Comment: Additionally the chmod isn't working for me. It is working if I use `chmod +x` though.

Comment: Sorry, it should be small `x` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to really execute the code inside the first `EOF`, this works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > scriptMaster.sh << EOF

`cat > script1.sh << EOF2
#code
EOF2

cat > script2.sh << EOF2
#code
EOF2`

EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that it's indented. Rather than messing around with `<<-` and tabs to try to strip the indenting, just don't indent any of it and use different end tokens in your embedded scripts so they don't accidentally terminate your master here doc:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > scriptMaster.sh << ENDMASTER

cat > script1.sh << EOF
#code
EOF

cat > script2.sh << EOF
#code
EOF

ENDMASTER
```

Comment: But this isn't the only reason why the code isn't working. Your script either isn't creating the 2 sub-scripts.

Comment: @bashophil No, this script only creates one script, `scriptMaster.sh`. Then, when `scriptMaster.sh` is in turn executed, two more scripts will be created. Isn't this what you meant by "Scriptception"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some old-school stuff (the concepts are the same as above):

```
echo "=== 001. Create script-01.sh"
sed 's/.//' >script-01.sh <<'//GO.SYSIN DD script-01.sh'
-echo This
-echo is a content
-echo of 'script-01.sh'
//GO.SYSIN DD script-01.sh
chmod +x script-01.sh

echo "=== 002. Create script-02.sh"
sed 's/.//' >script-02.sh <<'//GO.SYSIN DD script-02.sh'
-echo This is a content
-echo of 'script-02.sh'
//GO.SYSIN DD script-02.sh
chmod +x script-02.sh

echo "=== 999. EOF"
```